# How much did it cost to turnaround Rocketdyne F-1 test articles?

Tags: reuse, cost, f1

Despite being intended for an expendable vehicle, the F-1 [was tested and rated](https://space.stackexchange.com/a/63612/36625) for the equivalent of more than ten reflights.

[image]

How much did it cost to turnaround the test articles between the firings?